# How to filter numeric type of data and do data type conversion by using statistic functions in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Since statistics and calculation functions only support numerical types (int, double etc.) and do not support `text` types, is there any function in Apache IoTDB that can do data type conversion and filter numeric type of data? Because some of my data reported by measuring points are not all numerical types, so I want know is there any easier way for me check all the original `text` data type when writing query statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cast` function, which is able to convert the data in Apache IoTDB to the type specified by the `type` parameter set. This `type` parameter can also be set using regular expression to be verified.